# why preview image script is not working in html code?(checked old answers but non worked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to upload and preview an image in a web page. I have used so many online available templates/snippets but for some reasons non of them are working to preview the image(js file link is properly added and it is working). I'm unable to figure out that why JavaScript code is not running to preview that image. 
Lets take this which i took from another answer on stackOverFlow. It is working fine on 'Run Code Snippet'. But not working when i copy the code and use it.

```js
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.previewimg').show();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#uploadImg").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.previewimg {
  background: #ffff33;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.previewimg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="uploadImg" />
</form>

<div class="previewimg">
  <img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

I have used many many other snippets as well, image is uploading but preview isn't working.

Comment: In what way is it failing?  The code you show, as you have stated, appears to demonstrably work as expected.  What is the difference when you use it?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to work but Preview part is not working.

Comment: I have tried many different templates but, its still same. For some reason Preview isn't working

Comment: We can appreciate that you're having difficulty, but you're going to have to give us more than "it doesn't work".  Again, the code you have provided demonstrably works right here in your question.  When you "run the code snippet" on the question above, you're saying it fails for you?  After you select an image from your file system, you get no preview?  Is there an error on your browser's development console?

Comment: When i run this code, I get no preview. I can still get image from input field and store it to database but I'm not getting any preview.

Comment: It sounds like something may be different about your browser then.  Because the code in the question above works as expected here.  What browser are you using?  Again, is there any error or any message *at all* on the browser's development console?  (Such as a message indicating that file information was blocked for some reason?)  When you inspect the resulting HTML in your browser's debugging tools, is there an `<img>` element at all?  What does it contain?

Comment: Yes i am getting an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". and it references to this code **$("#uploadImg").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});**

Comment: If you're getting that error from the code snippet above then either `ajax.googleapis.com` is inaccessible to you or something is very broken in your web browser.  (Both are *extremely* unlikely.)  If you're getting that error in some *other* attempted use of the code above then what is that *other* code and how is it *different* from the code above?  (Hint: It's probably neglecting to include the library explictly referenced in the code above.)

Comment: No I haven't changed anything in this code. I'm running as it is... Is there a solution or something i could try.. I have to add this feature(preivew) in a form of my semester project.. :(

Comment: When the code fails, in your browser's debugging tools what is the response to the resource request for `jquery.min.js`?  I suppose your only alternative at this point is to use a locally hosted copy of jQuery, since for some reason you can't successfully access the CDN version.

Comment: I had put script file in <head> i just moved it below body of the page and it worked

Comment: But i dont understand that is the difference. Why it was not working in head

Comment: I can't know without a complete example.  Based on that description it's clear that you did indeed change *something* about the code to make it stop working.  Without seeing that complete example, all anybody can do is randomly guess.  My random guess is that you tried to use the jQuery library before loading it.

Comment: This is how i had out it in <head>                                                                                                                 <script src="myfile.js"></script>                                                                                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You were indeed trying to use jQuery *before* loading it.  The order in which you load your scripts is important.  Code is processed from start to finish.  (You were also getting an error that you had been ignoring all this time.  An error that, upon searching in Google, immediately finds examples explaining the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm new to this so i had no idea about order of loading scripts.
I had this in head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="this.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I was trying to use jQuery before loading it that generated **$is not defined** error. Just changed the order and it worked.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="this.css">
```

Thanks to **David**